# Promise return data cannot be assigned to class variable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-promise, ionic3

I am trying to assign the promise returned value to a variable but it is not assigning. I am still getting empty string when I console.log(this.imageref1).
The objective here is to get the data.downloadURL which will be returned after uploading the photo to the firebase. I need the downloadedURL. to store it in my database for the image path. I am stuck here, my database gets empty data for the downloadURL.

```
post_news(form: NgForm){

    this.title = form.value.title;
    this.content = form.value.content;
    this.category = form.value.category;


    console.log(this.capturedimage1);


    if(this.capturedimage1 !== ''){

        //console.log('captured image is not empty');



    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

    const filename = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);

    const imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${filename}.jpg`);

    let uploaded_file_path = `images/${filename}.jpg`;      


    imageRef.putString(this.capturedimage1, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then(data=>{

        this.imageref1 = data.downloadURL;

    });


    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that value is getting set -- eventually. Probably you are struggling with the fact that it happens after the enclosing function is done executing. For example here is a really simple test case:

```
function test(x) { 
  x.a = 1;
  Promise.resolve(true).then(_ => x.b = 2); 
  console.log(x);
}
```

The operation,

```
> test({c: 3})
{ c: 3, a: 1 }
undefined
```

logs an object which does not yet have `b: 2` in it, then returns `undefined`. That parameter is set, of course, eventually:

```
> test(abc = {c: 3})
{ c: 3, a: 1 }
undefined
> abc
{ c: 3, a: 1, b: 2 }
```

To understand what's really going on, you need to understand that all JS happens within the "event loop." JavaScript only allows one thing to happen at a time, so when you schedule other events to happen, JS has to follow the rule, "do everything in this function first, and then find something else that's been scheduled to happen."

Some function calls happen *synchronously*, they *block* the function call from moving forward until they complete. For example, `[1,2,3].forEach(x => console.log('hello, ' + x))` will log 3 strings to the console before completing. But the whole point of a **promised** value is that the computer is busy figuring it out, it's not available yet. Therefore, you can only actually use the value once it's found out, and all of your manipulations of the *promise* including adding a listener to `.then()` or `.catch()`, are *asynchronous* or *non-blocking*. The current function completes and those callbacks are put onto the event loop, to happen whenever the promised computation has been completed.

Comment: thxx for your  answer buddy!. ohh so that means whatever is in the .then({ ...will not block the flow of the function right? to force the .then({ function to be in the flow of the entire function do i have to set this whole thing 'imageRef.putString(this.capturedimage1, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then(data=>{ that.imageref1 = data.downloadURL; });' to a function ?

Comment: @Mikethetechy: you *cannot* go from asynchronous to synchronous. The runtime is saying "I am not going to stop on this," and there is no way to trick it into, "no, actually you're going to stop on this." If you are still in that function where the promise is defined, then that callback *has not fired yet* and *will not fire*: it is scheduled later. You have to think about the whole program asynchronously if one part of it is, so put any database-insert-whatevers into the `.then()` callback to happen when you know this value, rather than trying to do it before you know.

Comment: thx for your reply...now i get how asynchronous functions work..so the only way for me to do the database insert is in the .then() callback. however i have a list of images after i upload them i need to get the download url to store the download url in the database....its pretty challenging..regardsless which way i try i still need to get the download url...

Answer (score 3):

```
var that = this;
imageRef.putString(this.capturedimage1, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL)
.then(data=>{      
    that.imageref1 = data.downloadURL;
    return Promise.resolve(data.downloadURL);
})
.then(function(url){
    //make the db call.
});
```

Comment: thx for ur answer... so does that mean i can do smthng like this: var tmp_url = ''; imageRef.putString(this.capturedimage1, firebase.storage.StringFormat.DATA_URL).then(data=>{ tmp_url = data.downloadURL; }); this.imageref1 = tmp_url ?

Comment: @cr-drost pointed out, the then part execution happens aysnc. The code inside the then block might be executed at a later time. So in this case, the this.imageref1 = tmp_url might be executed before the then block, so it might not yield the result you expect.

Comment: so there is no way i can make it sync?

Comment: Don't try to make it sync call, please update the question with the actual intent and we can try to make it work the JS way.

Comment: i have updated the question. I need to get the dataurl to save the image path in my database. so this part where i am using .then({ to get the downloadURL is important. how can i get the downloadURL without the promise way?

Comment: The best and simplest implementation to capture 'this' instance. Thanks.